# Create Power Query Column Recursively

Tags: excel, powerquery, recursive-query

EMI Calculation:

```
Number.Round((rate/12*pv)/(1-Number.Power(1+rate/12,-nper)),0)
```

where PV is initial loan amount
Rate is the initial rate of interest at the beginning
and `nper is 180 = Tenure in months`

here the `EMI = 107485`

Keeping EMI Fixed, now i need to compute monthly interest and principal

The interest calculated formula will be
Previous balance * Rate of interest/12 * no. of days / no of days in the previous month
So if there is no rate change the interest will be prev bal * rate of interest /12 else it will be for the no of days new interest rate applicable.

```
Principal = EMI-Interest paid
New Balance = Previous Balance - Principal
Amount
```

What i am not able to achieve is :

Every time Interest is calculated, i want to refer to the previous balance which is not available.

I have tried creating Recursive functions to compute Interest, principal and balance columns:

Below function computes EMI value at the beginning

```
PMT

    (pv,rate,nper)=>
    let
    payment = Number.Round((rate/12*pv)/(1-Number.Power(1+rate/12,-nper)),0)
    in
    payment
```

Below function computes Interest amount (Index Value is the row number / payment no)

```
Get_InterestValue

    (indexValue,table,rate,no_of_days,no_of_days_in_Month)=>
    let
    prev_idx=indexValue-1,
    previousbal = get_previous_balance(indexValue,table),
    interest=previousbal*rate/12/no_of_days_in_Month*no_of_days
    in
    interest
```

Below function computes Principal amount paid

```
GetPrincipalPaid
    (indexvalue,table,EMI_amount,Interest_amount)=>
    let
    principal_amount= EMI_amount-Interest_amount
    in
    principal_amount
```

Below function computes Previous balance

```
get_previous_balance

    (index_value,table)=>
    let
    prev_idx=index_value-1,
    prev_bal=if prev_idx=0 then fParameter("ParameterTable","Initial_Loan_Amount") else Table.SelectRows(table, each ([Index] = prev_idx)){0}[Bal]
    in 
    prev_bal
```

fParameter function reads the intial values table

The columns gives errors

Comment: What column gives what error ?  Without sample data and code how are we supposed to reproduce and test this to help you ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution as in following code:

Now I am facing performance issue. Below solution works good with 10 Months or smaller. once u go for a higher Tenure, the calculations are very slow and doesnt generate any output for long time or probably crashes before calculations are completed,
is there any way i can speed up the query processing?

`PMT` Function:

```
(pv,rate,nper)=>
let
    payment = Number.Round((rate/12*pv)/(1-Number.Power(1+rate/12,-nper)),0)
in
    payment
```

`fParameter` Function:

```
let Parameter=(TableName,ParameterLabel) =>
let
    Source=Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name=TableName]}[Content],
    value=Source{[Parameter=ParameterLabel]}[Value]
in
    value
in Parameter
```

`Payment Schedule` Query:

```
let
    Custom1 = List.Generate(()=>Date.Month(fParameter("ParameterTable","StartDate")),each _<=fParameter("ParameterTable","Tenure_in_Months")*1.5+Date.Month(fParameter("ParameterTable","StartDate"))-1,each _+1),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Custom1, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Month", each if Number.Mod([Column1],12)=0 then 12 else Number.Mod([Column1],12)),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Year1", each Date.Year(fParameter("ParameterTable","StartDate"))+Number.RoundDown([Column1]/12)),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Year", each if [Month]=12 then [Year1]-1 else [Year1]),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Added Custom2",{{"Column1", "PaymentMonth"}}),
    #"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns1", "Payment Date", each #date([Year],[Month],Date.Day(fParameter("ParameterTable","StartDate")))),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom3",{"Payment Date"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Other Columns",{{"Payment Date", type date}}),
    #"Added Custom4" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "EMI", each EMIValue),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Custom4",{"Payment Date"},Loan_Rates,{"Date"},"Loan_Rates",JoinKind.FullOuter),
    #"Expanded Loan_Rates" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Loan_Rates", {"Date", "Loan Rate"}, {"Date", "Loan Rate"}),
    #"Added Custom5" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Loan_Rates", "New_Date", each if [Date] = null then [Payment Date] else [Date]),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Added Custom5",{{"New_Date", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Sorted Rows",{"Loan Rate"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filled Down",{"Payment Date", "Date"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"New_Date", "Payment Date"}}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Renamed Columns",{"Payment Date", "EMI", "Loan Rate"}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Reordered Columns", "Index", 0, 1),
    #"Added Index1" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Added Index", "Index.1", 1, 1),
    #"Merged Queries1" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Index1",{"Index"},#"Added Index1",{"Index.1"},"Added Index1",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Added Index1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries1", "Added Index1", {"Payment Date"}, {"Payment Date.1"}),
    #"Added Custom7" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Added Index1", "Payment.Date.2", each if [Index.1]=1 then fParameter("ParameterTable","Disbursement Date") else [Payment Date.1]),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom7",{{"Payment.Date.2", type date}}),
    #"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type1",{"Payment Date.1"}),
    #"Renamed Columns2" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns2",{{"Payment.Date.2", "Payment Date.1"}}),
    #"Added Custom6" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns2", "Days", each [Payment Date]-[Payment Date.1]),
    #"Extracted Days" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom6",{{"Days", Duration.Days, Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom8" = Table.AddColumn(#"Extracted Days", "No Of Days in Month", each Date.EndOfMonth([Payment Date.1])-Date.StartOfMonth([Payment Date.1])+#duration(1,0,0,0)),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom8",{"Index",  "Payment Date.1"}),
    #"Extracted Days1" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Columns1",{{"No Of Days in Month", Duration.Days, Int64.Type}}),
    #"Reordered Columns1" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Extracted Days1",{"Payment Date", "Days", "EMI", "Loan Rate"}),
    #"Renamed Columns3" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Reordered Columns1",{{"Index.1", "Index"}}),
    #"Reordered Columns2" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Renamed Columns3",{"Index", "Payment Date", "EMI", "No Of Days in Month", "Days", "Loan Rate"}),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Reordered Columns2",null,0,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"EMI"}),
    #"Invoked Custom Function" = Table.AddColumn(#"Replaced Value", "Interest", each Get_InterestValue([Index], Table.Buffer(#"Replaced Value"))),
    #"Added Custom9" = Table.AddColumn(#"Invoked Custom Function", "Principal", each [EMI]-[Interest]),
    #"Added Custom11" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom9", "Balance", each fParameter("ParameterTable","Initial_Loan_Amount")-List.Sum(List.FirstN(#"Added Custom9"[Principal],[Index]))),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom11", each [Interest] > 0)
    
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

`Loan_Rates` table Query == This reads change of loan rates over a period:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Loan_Rates"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}, {"Loan Rate", Percentage.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

`Get_InterestValue` Function

```
(indexValue,table)=>
let
    prev_idx=indexValue-1,
    rate=Table.SelectRows(table, each ([Index] = indexValue)){0}[Loan Rate],
    no_of_days_in_Month=Table.SelectRows(table, each ([Index] = indexValue)){0}[No Of Days in Month],
    no_of_days=Table.SelectRows(table, each ([Index] = indexValue)){0}[Days],
    previousbal = get_previous_balance(indexValue,table),
    interest=previousbal*rate/12/no_of_days_in_Month*no_of_days
in
    interest
```

`GetPrincipalPaid` Function:

```
(indexValue,table)=>
let
    EMI_Amount=Table.SelectRows(table, each ([Index] = indexValue)){0}[EMI],
    principal_amount= EMI_Amount-Get_InterestValue(indexValue,table)
in
    principal_amount
```

`GetBalance` Function:

```
(indexValue,table)=>
let
    bal = get_previous_balance(indexValue,table)-GetPrincipalPaid(indexValue,table) 
in
    bal
```

`get_previous_balance` function:

```
(indexValue,table)=>
let
prev_idx=indexValue-1,
prev_bal=if prev_idx=0 then fParameter("ParameterTable","Initial_Loan_Amount") else  GetBalance(prev_idx,table)
in 
prev_bal
```

`EMIValue` Function:
let

```
    Source = PMT(fParameter("ParameterTable","Initial_Loan_Amount"), fParameter("ParameterTable","Rate_int_PA"), fParameter("ParameterTable","Tenure_in_Months")),
    #"Converted to Table" = #table(1, {{Source}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Converted to Table",{{"Column1", "EMI"}}){0}[EMI]
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

Comment: Its very hard to figure out what you are doing, beyond the fact that you need to be using List.Accumulate over your data set so that you are not constantly calculating the same results over and over.

Comment: I am not sure how & where to use List.Accumulate 
I al figured out that following lines from Payment Schedule Query are causing query to run very slow:

    #"Invoked Custom Function" = Table.AddColumn(#"Replaced Value", "Interest", each Get_InterestValue([Index], Table.Buffer(#"Replaced Value"))),
    #"Added Custom9" = Table.AddColumn(#"Invoked Custom Function", "Principal", each [EMI]-[Interest]),
    #"Added Custom11" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom9", "Balance", each fParameter("ParameterTable","Initial_Loan_Amount")-List.Sum(List.FirstN(#"Added Custom9"[Principal],[Index]))),